# What's The Best Way To Write Multi-Line Code Snippets In VS-Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor, sublimetext, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

In [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/), multi-line code snippets can be defined with white-spaces in a snippet file.

But as far as I know, [VS-Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) needs a [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) entry. These require either:

1. Hard-breaks into a list of double-quoted strings, or
2. Soft-break a long string using line-breaks `\n`

This is inconvenient compared to the [WYSIWYG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) approaches other IDEs provide out of the box.

Are there better ways for defining long-blocks of code?

Answer (score 57):

You can define the body of your snippet as an array of strings, each beginning on a new line.

Like this:

```
  "Create for loop":{
    "prefix": "mkfor",
    "body":[
      "for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)",
      "{",
      "   //code goes here",
      "}"
    ],
   "description": "Creates a for loop"
  }
```

or if you install `Easy Snippet Maker` extension, you can create your snippets by highlighting texts.

Comment: Thanks. The snippet you gave here is the exact problem in my question: I don't want multiple double-quoted strings with commas. I'll give that extension a try.

Comment: Have you found a better solution to creating multiple lines without using a string for each line with comma?

Answer (score 21):

You can check out this video for a quick short tutorial

https://youtu.be/g1ouTcFxQSU

Go to **File --> Preferences --> User Snippets**. Select your preferred language.
Now type the following code to make a for loop snippet:

```
  "Create for loop":{
    "prefix": "for",
    "body":[
      "for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)",
      "{",
      "   //code goes here",
      "}"
    ],
   "description": "Creates a for loop"
  }
```

You are done.
Type "for" in the editor and use the first prediction.

***SHORTCUT--***

1. install [Snippet-creator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nikitaKunevich.snippet-creator) extension.
2. Highlight the code that you need to make snippet.
3. press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and type "Create snippet" on the command palette and
   press ENTER.
4. select language for which you want to create snippet(eg:-CPP), then type 
   snippet name, type snippet shortcut and then type snippet description.
   You are now good to go.
   Type the snippet shortcut in the editor that you entered in step 4, and select the
    prediction (if no prediction comes press ctrl+space) that comes first.

Hope this helps :)

Note: goto File->Preferences->User Snippets. Then select the language in which you
created the snippet. You will find the snippet there.

Comment: Additionnal note: as a Mac user you can access your snippets from **Code**->Preferences->User Snippets.

Comment: @moff [CMD] + [SHIFT] + [P] (mac users)

Comment: Side note: the snippet creator has been marked as deprecated

Answer (score 9):

I cannot find a good way to create multi-line snippets either. It's probably one of the features I'd like to see improved the most. As another answer suggested, there are a couple extensions out there to help with Snippet creation (like [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tariky.easy-snippet-maker) and [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nikitaKunevich.snippet-creator)). However, they don't escape literal dollar signs and indentation isn't great.

When browsing for answers to this, I stumbled across a [Pen by Denis Malinochkin](https://codepen.io/mrmlnc/pen/GqrqPg) (linked from [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/15140)). However, it also did not escape dollar signs properly, so I forked it and added this line to handle literal dollar signs. **Here it is: https://codepen.io/cbejensen/pen/WXLxaE**

Hope that helps!

P.S. - This is the line I added:

```
line = line.replace(new RegExp(/\$/, 'g'), '\\$');
```

Comment: Thanks! That's crazy that one must hack to make this work.

Comment: Note that the reason why the [original pen](https://codepen.io/mrmlnc/pen/GqrqPg) didn't escape dollar signs, because VS Code uses `$1`, `$2`, etc to position the cursor after you've activated the snippet

Comment: Good point, can't believe I overlooked that! I've updated the pen to account for numbers following dollar signs, though of course many snippets may want literal dollar signs before numbers. I guess there's no great way to account for literal dollar signs and I probably should have left the original pen as it was.

Answer (score 5):

I've created an extension to store snippets in a markdown file:

[image: demo_image]

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=usernamehw.snippets-in-markdown

Answer (score 2):

Hit cmd+shift+p on mac machine, and search for "Configure User Snippets" then create a file and paste below json code.
provide prefix, Body, and description. 
Reference: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets

```
{
    "forLoop": {
        "prefix": "forLoop",
        "body": [
            "for (const ${2:element} of ${1:array}) {",
            "\t$0",
            "}"
        ],
        "description": "For Loop"
    },

    "reactClass": {
        "prefix": "reactClass",
        "body": [
            "import React from 'react';",
            "class ${1:ComponentName} extends React.Component {",
            "\t$0constructor(props) {",
            "\t$0\t$0super(props)",
            "",
            "render() {",
            "return (<div> ${2:Component} </div>)",
            "}",
            "export default ${3:ComponentName}"
        ],
        "description": "For React Component class"
    },
    "function": {
    "scope": "javascript,typescript",
    "prefix": "function",
    "body": [
        "import React from 'react';",
        "import withStyles from '@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles';",
        "import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';",
        "",
        "import Styles from  './style.js';",
        "",
        "const useStyles = makeStyles(Styles);",
        "",
        "function $1(props){",
        "const classes = useStyles();",
        "\treturn (",
        "\t\t<React.Fragment>",
        "\t\t\t<div className={classes.root}>",
        "\t\t\t\t$1",
        "\t\t\t</div>",
        "\t\t</React.Fragment>",
        "\t)",
        "}",
        "export default withStyles(useStyles)($1);"
    ],
    "description": "react class"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this JSON Escape formatter(?) to process a large amount of HTML into a snippet:

https://www.freeformatter.com/json-escape.html

(The result of this process should be added in quotes "..." into the "body" part of the JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a script which you can create your own complex snippets. just using the file you'd like. so you dont' need to write the source code in a string or string array.
https://github.com/banxi1988/vscode-snippets-ext-template

Answer (score 0):

As of October 31, 2023, using VSCode 1.83.1, I was able to create a VSCode equivalent of JetBrains IntelliJ's built-in "psvm" short-cut for Java via the following entry into file java.json located in directory %AppData%\Code\User\snippets\ :

```
"public static void main": 
{
    "prefix": "psvm",
    "description": "Creates an empty static main method",
    "body" : [
    "public static void main(String[] args)",
    "{",
    "\t$0",
    "}"
    ]
}
```